# Can't archive project when use new MagicalRrecord

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, magicalrecord

I add to my project MagicalRecord as submodule as described here

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Installing-MagicalRecord.md

Then i add it's to my project and i got modified content on submodule.
Just then i open my project.

[image]

Why? And also i can't archive my project, because can't found [image]

I added MagicalRecord frame work to Link libraries but it's red

[image]

But it's build and run on simulator or iphone device.

Problem just then try make archive my app.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using the CocoaPods method.  I have used it for MagicalRecord many times with no issues.  Relatively easy to install and keeps your code up to date.

I also ran into a similar issue when I tried a submodule and couldn't get it to work.  Make sure your project has CoreData.framework linked and also trying linking libMagicalRecord.dylib and libMagicalRecord.a.